# Show pointwise converegent for Fourier serie

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

We let $f\in$$PC_{2\pi}$ and $f$ be $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$, $x\in[-\pi,\pi$].
I have to found out if the Fourier serie for the function is pointwise convergent on $x\in(-\pi,\pi$) or not?

I have this theorem I think I can use:
If $f\in$$PC_{2\pi}$ and let $x_0$$\in R$ be an point where $f$ is 
continuous and differentiable from both sides. Then is the Fourier serie for $f$ pointwise convergent in $x_0$ with the sum $f(x_0)$.

I think I have to check if:
$\frac{f(x_0+t)-f(x_0)}{t}$ have a limiting value for $t->$$0$. Is that correct. But how can I formally check that?

Comment: Hint: Graph your function, does it look differentiable everywhere?

Comment: It's look like it is not differentiable in x=0. But how can I formally show it's not differentiable and therefore is the Fourier serie for $f$ not pointwise convergent?

Comment: For pointwise convergence, you don't need differentiability.

Comment: I the first line did you mean  Fourier series instead of Taylor series?

Comment: Yes I mean Fourier serie. Sorry. Is it fixed now

Answer (score 1):

$|e^{-|x|}-e^{-|y|}| \leq ||x|-|y||e^{\pi}$ by MVT applied to the function $e^{x}$. This gives $|e^{|x|}-e^{|y|}| \leq |x-y|e^{\pi}$.  Hence $f$ is of bounded varation. For any continuous function of bounded variation  the Fourier series converges **uniformly**.

Comment: It makes sense that if the Fourier series converges uniformly then it also converges pointwise by definition. But in my book it says that if F (of causeF'=f) is 
continuous and piecewise differentiable and if F'=f for all non-break-points then is the Fourier serie for F uniformly convergent can I use that?

Comment: @Lifeni Our function $f$ is differentiable at all points except $1$ and you can certainly use that theorem. (The derivative id $-e^{-x}$ for $x >0$ and $e^{x}$ fro $x <0$).